# Problem with the Group BY Clause

Tags: sql, group-by

HI Guys

I have a table like the bellow one

```
SurveyID(uniqueidentifier) PKey,UserID(uniqueidentifier),Time(DateTime)
```

I can have duplicated for UserID and Time is the taken as the current time when we insert a record to the table.

I have to select the last inserted recrod for each user.

All my queries are failing. Any help on this?

Thanks
Tutu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT u1.*
FROM Users u1
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT *
     FROM Users u2
     WHERE u1.ID = u2.ID AND u2.Date > u1.Date)
```

Comment: HI I can have more than one user in the same table. I need to get the last inserted record for each user. Previous query will not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH rows AS (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY [Time] DESC) AS __ROW,
        SurveyID,
        PKey,
        UserID
    FROM yourTable
)
SELECT SurveyID, PKey, UserID
FROM rows
WHERE __ROW = 1;
```

This will work in Oracle and SQL Server.  Not sure about MySQL or Postgres.  It won't work in Access.  The double-underscore __ROW is just a naming convention I find myself using sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by userid order by time desc) as sno from users
) as t
where sno=1
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * 
FROM Users
WHERE Time IN
    (SELECT max(Time) 
     FROM Users 
     GROUP BY USerID)